# javaw keeps restoring itself

Tags: java, windows, javaw

My `javaw.exe` process is infinitely restoring itself launching a windows error windows saying

> A Java Exception has ocurred

I've tried taskkill, windows task manager and they keep coming back. How do I fix this?

Comment: can you share the trace of the error?

Comment: find parent process , or kill process subtree , or check whether a service is  up and spawning processes

Comment: Tried all those methods, didn't work...

Comment: go to process file location and move the .jar , or shift - delete it , or change JAVA_HOME dir

Comment: I already solved the problem by myself. I did change the JAVA_HOME environment variable, didn't work as well. The jar couldn't be moved as it was "being used by another program"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to stop the infinite cycle. It's not a very formal way but worked. I tried to restart Windows, pressed "Force restart" when it listed processes that were still running and when I saw that javaw had been forcibly shutdown, I canceled the restart.